# KeyPress event fails outside the VBA Editor in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA code and part of the code, specifically the spacebar keypress event works (although not always) when it is run in the VBA Editor in MS Word. But outside, i.e. if I include the module in the `normal.dotm` or put it as `.dotm` in MS Word's STARTUP folder, then assign the macro to a button in MS Word and try to run it, the code does not work properly. The code works, but the part that handles the spacebar keypress event does not.

I am using MS Office 2010 Version 14.0.7229.5000 (64-bit). If it matters, all MS Office apps are run on a server and we are clients accessing the apps through `RDP` protocol.

Declaration part

```
    #If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As 
    Long) As Integer
    #End If
    Private Const VK_SPACE = &H20
```

and the part that is supposed to handle the keypress event

```
    Do Until GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)
        'exit when Spacebar key is pressed
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

Comment: I forgot to add that my pc (client pc) runs on linux (xubuntu) but the graphical interface looks like Windows'. The RDP client is Remina connecting to MS Windows Server 2012 R2 on the server. May be I should use Linux's libraries, but I am not sure because the MS Office apps run on the Windows server, not on the client pc.

Comment: Why aren't you using actual event handlers?

Comment: How do I do that? The code is supposed to do the following: it converst a number to text in MS Word, then waits for user to type a word and when the user presses a spacebar, it writes something else based on what the user typed. The code uses no forms.